# Webpack third party min files bundling

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

I have a set of vendor xxx.min.js files. Previously I was using ASP.NET Optimization bundling to bundle all these files together in one bundle and this was working good.  Right now we are migrating to ASP.NET core without server-side bundling anymore so we need to use client-side bundling.

I want to do the same thing with webpack. It doesn't seem to be working well because webpack is trying to interpret the minified code and throwing all kinds of errors. But I want some kind of mechanism so that webpack doesn't go interpret these minified files and just glue these files together just as with ASP.NET Optimization server-side bundling.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

For this u can use a webpack plugins such as:

- **ConcatPlugin**: this will bundle files together without webpack boiler plate code. U could use it to bundle legacy javascript together.
  https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-concat-plugin
- **MergeIntoSingleFilePlugin**: https://github.com/markshapiro/webpack-merge-and-include-globally

This will help just bundle stuff together without having a modular webpack interpretation. You can use this to bundle vendor code together or if you have legacy code.

Just make sure to use the standard entry property for new stuff :)